# React JS error : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs

I'm a React beginner
Why do you get this error?
Line 6:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
I need your help

full code :

```
function getNumbers() {
  const candidate = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  const array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
    const chosen = candidate.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - i)), 1)[0];
    array.push[chosen];
  }
  return array;
}

export default getNumbers;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array.push` is a function, so you use parentheses, not square brackets. Like so:

`array.push(chosen)`